# MPC handler - how to stop the spinning activity monitor?

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a multiplayer game and it simply connects via the MPC Handler. The connect window shows the people nearby and connected players. There's one of those spinning activity icons and it continues search spinning even though peers have successfully connected. It's not a button or Activity Indicator View. It's just there as part of the handler so I don't know how to stop it after a player has connected. Any ideas? Thanks. Screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVwGE.png

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class MPCHandler: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate {

var peerID:MCPeerID!
var session:MCSession!
var browser:MCBrowserViewController!
var advertiser:MCAdvertiserAssistant? = nil

func setupPeerWithDisplayName (displayName:String){
    peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: displayName)
}

func setupSession(){
    session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
    session.delegate = self
}

func setupBrowser(){
    browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "my-game", session: session)
}

func advertiseSelf(advertise:Bool){
    if advertise{
        advertiser = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "my-game", discoveryInfo: nil, session: session)
        advertiser!.start()
    }else{
        advertiser?.stop()
        advertiser = nil
    }

}

func session(session: MCSession!, peer peerID: MCPeerID!, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
    let userInfo = ["peerID":peerID, "state":state.rawValue]
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MPC_DidChangeStateNotification", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    })
}

func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!) {
    let userInfo = ["data":data, "peerID":peerID]
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MPC_DidReceiveDataNotification", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    })
}

func session(session: MCSession!, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, atURL localURL: NSURL!, withError error: NSError!) {

}

func session(session: MCSession!, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withProgress progress: NSProgress!) {

}

func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream!, withName streamName: String!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't.  That connection browser GUI is provided by the MPC framework and there is no call in the API to squelch that.

But if your app only allows two peers in a session, when you get the didChangeState of a connected opposite peer, you can hide the browser programmatically (not waiting for the user to click Cancel or Done.)  And you should stopAdvertiser (since you don't support more connections after two peers are joined.)

I suppose that spinning wheel means "looking for more peers to come into range" and doesn't mean "user cannot click any buttons."  I agree with you, it is somewhat strange.  The framework lets you implement your own connection browser.